# Link React Native front end with serverless node.js back end

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am in the middle of creating an app for a college project with a friend. We have the front end (`React Native`) and the back end (serverless node.js) working separately but are now looking to link the two (for want of a better word) so the front end will use the back end to perform whatever action is required when any given button is pressed.

The main problem is that we don't know how to do this?

Anything I was able to find online was to do with `ReactJS` so any guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

**Additional info:**

- Any functions are contained in the back end code but are handled by other API's (google calendar API, for example)
- We want to call the functions on the backend and have them do whatever it is they're supposed to do
- We need to find a way to connect this functionality with the UI

Comment: Take a look at RESTful APIs https://www.restapitutorial.com/

Comment: One more link to help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Client%E2%80%93server_architecture

Comment: @BrunoEduardo thanks, I'll take a look at those and hopefully they'll help!

Comment: Feel free to ask me stuff.

Comment: Tank you, I really appreciate that!

Comment: If you have your API ready to use, in React Native you use `fetch` (if it is REST) to hit your endpoint or Apollo for `graphql`.

Comment: You can use axios https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios, if your endpoints are ready to use.